# MS Access-2019, Data Type Mismatch

Tags: ms-access, calculated-field, mismatch

I am relatively new to MS Access-2019.

I'm attempting to create a calculated field from an adjacent field. I receive the following error message when I write the argument in the calculated field:

> Data Type Mismatch in the Criteria Expression

Online research and the use of library references tell me that I'm attempting to create a calculated field with data with different attributes.

However, a careful review of the "criteria in the expression" does not seem to support this error message.

Specifically, the expression in the calculated field is:

```
LateFee:[AmountPd]*0.02
```

As you can see this is not a complex expression.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete SQL statement.

Comment: Data Type Mismatch **in the Criteria Expression** doesn't really point to a problem regarding the calculated field... We need to see the complete query or a functional stripped one which also causes the problem.

Comment: This could happen if AmountPd holds text - like,say, a formatted number.